# What would happen if two IIS redirect to each other?

Tags: iis, redirect

What would happen if, I put 301 redirect in IIS 6 for one web site (A) to redirect to site (B), then for the very same page, having IIS 7 for site (B), redirect back to the old page in (A).

Are they going to cause an infinite back and forth redirect?  Or are they going to cancel each other out?

for example:

(A)  IIS6:   www.example.com/123      redirect to         www.example.net/abc
(B)  IIS7:   www.example.net/abc      redirect back to    www.example.com/123

Comment: infinite loop, but some browsers (chrome at least, likely the rest) will detect that and stop

Comment: Try it and tell us how it went!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP 301 is a *status code* not a *request*. It will be up to the browsers rather than the web server, as the web server would not "know" that you've been redirected back. Most browsers<sup>1</sup> [should detect a redirect loop](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3) and stop with an error.

<sub>1. I know this to be true with Chrome and relatively recent FF, no idea about IE...but I'd imagine this would be detected.</sub>